# ES6 twitter-text import

Tags: javascript, twitter, es6-modules

I'm trying to import the [twitter-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-text) package into a React/ES6 environment, and I'm not able to figure out what exactly is exported and keep getting `...is not exported from 'twitter-text'.` compile errors.

Doc states that the `twttr.txt` namespace is exported, but all the examples I can find are for node and use `require()`. It installed fine via `npm install twitter-text` and it's finding refs, for example `import { parseTweet } from 'twitter-text';` is grabbing actual function and class refs from the package, but still the no export error when it compiles.

I also tried to get the global `twttr.txt` using just `import 'twitter-text';` but  I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library is [default-exporting an object](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/blob/master/js/src/index.js#L53-L101) unfortunately, which means that you need to use

```
import twttr from 'twitter-text'

twttr.parseTweet(…)
```

Named exports do not seem to be available.

Comment: ah I see. I've spent some time away from js, so thanks for unblocking me